# What are the kubernetes pod phases equivalence to pod status?

Tags: kubernetes

I need to know what are the all possible `STATUS` a `kubernetes` `pod` can have.

**My Problem: - I found these status by using `kubectl get pods` command**

- Running
- Pending
- ImagePullBackOff
- CrashLoopBackOff
- Completed

**But when I open the `yaml` file for a pod which it says `Completed` in its STATUS, `yaml` definition is Succeeded. This is its `phase`**

So that means, it in `yaml` there is another value and when I use `kubectl get pods` it gives another value.

These are the `pod phases` in `yaml` definitions:

- Pending
- Running
- Succeeded
- Failed
- Unknown

**I want to know what would I get as the equivalence to these above commands when I execute `kubectl get pods` (eg: I get `Completed` for `Succeeded`) ?**

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes is setting a Status to the pod (so status is Primary), status itself can have Phase.
So for example **Status** `Completed` can be assigned to Phase `Succeeded` and Phase `Failed`, While **Status** `Running`  can't be assigned to this phase.

But in general, it's almost the same Running is Running, Pending is Pending. Phases `Unknown` as far as I remember means node is unreachable, and can't report pod status.

As official documentation states:

> A Pod’s status field is a PodStatus object, which has a phase field.
>
> The phase of a Pod is a simple, high-level summary of where the Pod is in its lifecycle. The phase is not intended to be a comprehensive rollup of observations of Container or Pod state, nor is it intended to be a comprehensive state machine.
>
> The number and meanings of Pod phase values are tightly guarded. Other than what is documented here, nothing should be assumed about Pods that have a given phase value.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/

Comment: So you are saying it is better to check the phase in the `yaml` manifest file to explicitly understand the problem with the pod right? Since statuses like `Completed` might mean different things at different times

Comment: I guess its better to update my answer with a quote of official pod lifesycle page, which gives a better understanding of phases.

Comment: @JananathBanuka; It is better to rely on status and ready check (kubectl get pods will show both columns); not on phase because pod phases can be misleading; eg Even in running phase we can have pods with status Error, Terminating, Crashloop etc. another eg is Failed and running, both phases can have pod with status complete.
Go with status column check along with if pod is Ready (x/x) or not.